# Getting Error while Deleting Row in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add and delete a row in GridView and getting this error: `CS1061: 'webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Grd1_onrowdeleting'` and `no accessible extension method 'Grd1_onrowdeleting' accepting a first argument of type 'webform1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

**Webform1.aspx:**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="Grd1"   runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="1306px" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="Grd1_onrowdeleting" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
               
                        
            </asp:GridView>
```

**webform1.aspx.cs code:**

```
protected void Grd1_onrowdeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
            DataTable dt = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
            dt.Rows[index].Delete();
            ViewState["dt"] = dt;
            Gbind();  this is a function
        }
```

Comment: protected void Grd1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e){}

Comment: set to onrowdeleting="Grd1_RowDeleting"

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: rebuild project and try again after MMK 's solution

Comment: Done after rebuilding the project. Thank you both.